Devspace failing to find entrypoint sh file when running "devspace dev"
I have a configuration running several applications, some dbs, ect... inside Kubernetes. This is deployed with Rancher / Helm and we are using devspace to do local file sync / development work with those container images.
devspace dev throws the following error on their machines only, it works on my machine:

sh: 1: /usr/local/apache2/devspace_start.sh: not found

Devspace is able to fully complete creating the SSH session with the container, start the ssh server on the container, start and complete file sync, and then fails to find this file.
Console output from running devspace dev:
info Using kube context 'rancher-desktop'
deploy:app Deploying chart ../my-chart/ (my-chart) with helm...
deploy:app Deployed helm chart (Release revision: 1)
deploy:app Successfully deployed app with helm
Execute hook 'run-make-api' at after:deploy
Waiting for running containers for hook 'run-make-api'
Execute hook 'run-make-api' in container 'default/api-container-56c75c7d86-kjg6r/api-container'
dev:app Waiting for pod to become ready...
dev:app Selected pod api-container-devspace-75d5698c76-cv88q
dev:app ports Port forwarding started on: 33285 -> 80
dev:app sync  Sync started on: ./ <-> ./
dev:app sync  Waiting for initial sync to complete
dev:app sync  Initial sync completed
dev:app proxy Port forwarding started on: 10444 <- 10567
dev:app ssh   Port forwarding started on: 11789 -> 8022
dev:app ssh   Use 'ssh app.api-container.devspace' to connect via SSH
dev:app term  Opening shell to api-container:api-container-devspace-75d5698c76-cv88q (pod:container)
sh: 1: ./devspace_start.sh: not found

The path in question that I've specified in devspace.yaml (seen below) changes per project but I've verified they are all correct by connecting via kubectl exec -- /bin/bash into the same container image and verifying the file is there and permissions look correct. I have also tried this with relative paths ./devspace_start.sh but the issue persisted on their machines despite both ways working for me.
    terminal:
      command: /usr/local/apache2/devspace_start.sh

ls -la inside the container directory in question shows:
root@api-container-74895f9fff-f8z5l:/usr/local/apache2# ls -la
total 60
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data 4096 May 30 17:18 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     4096 May 14 02:55 ..
...
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root     root     1741 May 30 17:16 devspace_start.sh

The file is definitely on the container, and since the images should be functionally the same given the nature of Dockerfiles, I have to assume something is different with my local configuration of devspace that is missing on their machines? Is it possible the container might be getting emulated slightly differently in some way that could affect this?
I've had them check with other projects (with other paths i've verified) and they have the same issue. I've also checked the logs inside the .devspace folder in the local directory but only have errors related to networks being closed. Additionally, I did plenty of debugging related to the building of the docker image itself, including fully clearing the build cache and recreating it on their machines locally, but the issue persisted.
I'm pretty new to devspace and it seems great so far aside from this one major issue, so any help would be appreciated...
